# Saving None into MongoDB using MongoEngine Dynamic Document

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

I am trying to save a MongoEngine Document into a Dynamic Document. Sample code is as follows:

```
class Small(mongoengine.Document):
    var_1 = mongoengine.IntField(db_field="var_1")
    var_2 = mongoengine.IntField(db_field="var_2")

class Main(mongoengine.DynamicDocument):
    timeseries = mongoengine.ListField(mongoengine.EmbeddedDocumentField('Small'),
                                       db_field="timeseries")

    def sample_insert():
        input = [(2, 4), (2, 6), (3, None), (4, None)]

        to_insert = [Small(var_1=i[0], var_2=i[1]) for i in input]

        self.timeseries = to_insert
        self.save()
```

The problem I am having occurs when one or more of the values to be saved is None. In this case the following error is generated:

```
mongoengine.errors.ValidationError: ValidationError (Data:55c0d57d1853bcad5c17b1f7) (var_1.Field is required)
```

I could set the None values to 0, but this is not a good solution as I can no longer distinguish between legitimate 0 values and non-existing values.

What I would love to do is be able to insert these None values as a 'null' entry into MongoDB.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I had no problem running your code. The document inserted looks like this:

```
"timeseries" : [{ "var_1" : 2, "var_2" : 4 }, { "var_1" : 2, "var_2" : 6 }, { "var_1" : 3 }, { "var_1" : 4 }]
```

Before I could've run the code, I had to put `self` as an argument of your `sample_insert` function.